# Byte addressed mem and word addressed

Tags: c, memory

What does it mean by word addressed memory and byte addressed memory?

Comment: Can you tell us the context in which you encountered these ?

Comment: An array of int is word addressed, and array of char (assuming 8 bit char) is byte addressed.

Comment: @user315052: nope - the terms relate to computer architecture

Answer (score 4):

This is normally used in the context of the underlying hardware. Most systems nowadays have byte addressed memory. That is to say, that each byte in the memory can be individually addressed and fetched.

Some systems have word addressed memory, and pointer registers contain the addresses of individual words. Moreover, whenever memory is fetched, a whole word is fetched. If you need a specific byte, the compiler will fetch a word and then arrange to get the required byte out of that.

Note that on a system like that, using reinterpret_cast on a pointer is extremely dangerous, as the implementation will probably (for efficiency) keep pointers to word aligned thing as word pointers, and pointers to byte aligned things as byte pointers. So if your memory looks a bit like this:

```
 word X  : aa ab ac ed
 word X+1: ba bb bc bd
```

A pointer to word X will contain X, but a byte pointer to aa will contain X*4

`reinterpret_cast<word *>(&aa)` will give you a word pointer of X*4 which will be embarrassingly wrong.

On a byte addressed machine, both word and byte pointers will contain X*4, so it is 'safe' (that is to say undefined behavior and confusing) to reinterpret_cast between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Tom...in word access memory you can have whole 4 bytes when accessed to memory(like in AHB bus) For this type of memory,if  u try to access byte you will get undefined behaviour